# Redirect to previous page after logged in without using query string

Tags: php

Is there another way to redirect to a previous page after the user is logged in without storing the redirect URL to the query string. I have only seen examples using the query string, but I want to implement this without storing the redirect URL to the query string. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing the redirect url in the query string, you could store it in the session like this:

```
$_SESSION['login-redirect'] = '/some-path.php'
```

Then, you can just redirect like this:

```
$loginRedirectUrl = '/default-path.php'
if (isset($_SESSION['login-redirect'])) $loginRedirectUrl = $_SESSION['login-redirect'];
header('Location: '.$loginRedirectUrl);
```

Comment: i got some concept from this. I will write my answer in code igniter.

Comment: i got some concept from this. I will write my answer in code igniter.

Comment: If this was helpful for you, can you mark the answer as accepted so it shows up as answered to anyone else who is searching for this?  http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Answer (score 0):

In Controller:

```
 public function product()
 {
     if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        $data["refined_product_category"] = $this->cmsdbmodel->refined_product();
        $this->load->view('cms/header');

        $this->load->view('cms/products',$data);
        $this->load->view('cms/footer');
     }
     else {
        $url = current_url();  //gets your current url.
        $this->session->set_userdata("sess_url", $url);  //keeps your current url in session.
        $this->index();
     }
}
```

then in login page.

```
public function login()
{
   if (login success) {
      redirect($this->session->userdata("sess_url"));  //retrieve the url that was in session and redirect.
   }
}
```

I did this and it worked for me.